# Set secure flag only for external app not internal app

Tags: web-applications, cookies, asp.net

In an ASP.NET app, I can set the secure flag in this way: httpCookies requireSSL="true"

Now imagine my application is faced externally, with an admin console facing internally to the organization. If for some reason we cannot or don't want to use SSL internally, is there any way to set the "Secure" flag for the external application, and not set it for the internal admin pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The httpCookies tag does have a domain attribute.

```
<httpCookies domain="String" 
         httpOnlyCookies="true|false" 
         requireSSL="true|false" />
```

So you could theoretically have 2 applications with 2 distinct domains, one for public facing with requireSSL="true" that only has the external pages and one for admin pages with requireSSL="false".

But if you are already going to get an SSL certificate for the external users, couldn't you use that same certificate for internal users also? Using SSL is best practice even for internal network traffic as [session hijacking is very easy](http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/hacking-tutorial/firesheep-http-session-hijacking-tools/#sthash.CDPFKfIc.dpbs) if cookies are sent in the clear.

Comment: You are right, good practice is to use the certificate for the internal admin page too. I totally agree. The problem is the external app SSL traffic terminates on a load balancer, but the internal admin app does not go through the load balancer. So we actually have to install the certificate on IIS.

Comment: If the SSL traffic terminates on the load balancer then the public facing SSL certificate will need to be installed on the load balancer not the IIS server. All traffic from the load balancer and internal users will then come to the IIS server unencrypted. The best solution would be to install a another SSL certificate on the IIS server as well. That way all traffic will be encrypted and you will not have to spilt the application.